# Background image for submit button not working

Tags: css

My first background image for the form fields works, but the second one for the submit button is doing nothing, & the button is using the style of the fields.

My CSS is this:

```
form input {
    background: url("images/text-field1.png") no-repeat scroll -5px 0 transparent;
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 17px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    width: 311px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

form input .button1 {
    background: url("images/submitbutton.png") no-repeat scroll -5px 0 transparent;
}
```

button1 is a class that only styles the button, but for some reason it is not styling it.

Comment: Why don't you use `input type="image"`?

Comment: What browser? Add fiddle example

Comment: Your CSS Selector might be wrong. If I am right then it must be like this `form input.button1`. Please post your HTML.

Comment: I use input type="submit" for the form, am using chrome, & my html is:

<input class="button_submit1"
type="submit"
class="button1" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

I have given button class name `mybtn` and applied background-image style.

HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="mybtn"/>
```

CSS

```
input.mybtn {
    background-image: url("http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/symphony.png");
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/1zvtLw55/2/)**

Comment: This sort of works, I now have some black text saying "submit" over my image though. Do you have a fix for that?

Comment: Yes we can remove text and show the background image text. check it out update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/1zvtLw55/1/

Comment: Thanks, adding the negative indent hid the text. One last thing, the left of the image is being cut off, is this something that can happen with this code, or is it an entirely seperate problem?

Comment: Adjust padding based on your image width & height

Comment: I've added padding:100px; and I still have part of my image cut. I have tested with several images & specified height & width.

Comment: I cannot help you without seeing your image. You just try to adjust width & height.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/2vKMwMn.png

There's the image. See the left side is cut off. I have adjusted width to larger than image size & the same, & also left it unspecified. I have adjusted margins & padding too. Could anything else be causing this?

Comment: Its not the problem CSS. problem with image only. your image left side is cut off.

Comment: No lol the image I uploaded has that part, I am saying that this is happening with every image I input as the background image with this CSS, what I have uploaded is the screenshot of the image, not the one I am adding to the page. http://i.imgur.com/okaRdo8.png This is the image I am trying to add.

Comment: Please share your code in JSFIDDLE with background image

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CrowStorm/o3jno2cu/ There, I don't know what this JSFIDDLE site is but for some reason its made a ton of buttons lol.

Comment: Thanks! I had to specify height again because the bottom was cut off this time, but that worked. Mods can close this, if that's how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `!important`

otherwise, the base class, which uses `!important` on it's default EMPTY `background-image` property will override you.

you will need something like

```
background-image: url("images/submitbutton.png") no-repeat scroll -5px 0 transparent  !important;
```